# IIS Express crashing asp.net 3.1 utf8 encoding

Tags: asp.net-core

I used this function all the time in asp.net mvc to fetch data from an API but in asp.net core it's crashing out. I believe it may be an issue to do with the utf8  in .net core has anyone else had issues with this I just get an iis express error of -1 and the code bombs out

```
public async Task<List<Stock>> GetStockFromApi()
{    
    List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.GetALlStock, string.Empty));
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
       var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
       var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(content);
     }
   return _result.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your api result (`byteArray`) in your case is correct.

It works well when I use your code in a brand new asp.net core 3.1 mvc project:

1.Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package to project from PMC

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.1.0
```

2.Register it in startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

3. Test Action:

```
public async Task<List<Stock>> GetStockFromApi()
    {
        List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
        var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44321/home/GetAllStock");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(content);
            }
            return _result.ToList();
        }

    }
public ActionResult<List<Stock>> GetAllStock()
    {
        var list = new List<Stock>()
        {
            new Stock()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name="hello"
            },
            new Stock()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name="wrold"
            },
        };
        return Ok(list);
    }
```